# ASP.NET Core Web Api Update/PUT Method reordering Postgres database records

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi, npgsql, asp.net-core-7.0

I am new to C# / .NET Core, and I am creating an app with REST API CRUD methods with the ASP.NET Core 7 Web API (NOT ASP.NET MVC). It appears I got Create, Read, and Delete working correctly, but not Update/PUT, at least not in an optimal state.

When I update a record, the order of my records by ID changes when saved to the database (Postgres). My unique IDs are incrementing integers.

For example, if I have three review records saved in the database:

```
[
    { id: 1, review: "Test1" }, 
    { id: 2, review: "Test2" }, 
    { id: 3, review: "Test3" }
]
```

and proceed to update the record with id==1, then the order is saved in the database as follows:

```
[
    { id: 2, review: "Test2" }, 
    { id: 3, review: "Test3" }, 
    { id: 1, review: "Updated Review" }
]
```

I would think this would be problematic because Postgres GETs records by ID using binary search. I can't do a binary search when records are not ordered. I'm using an Angular frontend, but I get the same unexpected result when I use Postman.

I attempted to write an update method in my controller and utilize the corresponding service. Here is the beginning of my controller.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using backend.Models;
using backend.Services;

namespace backend.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/reviews")]
public class ReviewsController : ControllerBase
{
    private ReviewsService _reviewsService;
    private readonly ILogger<ReviewsController> _logger;

    public ReviewsController(ReviewsService reviewsService, ILogger<ReviewsController> logger)
    {
        this._reviewsService = reviewsService;
        this._logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And the Update/Put method:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Review> UpdateReview(int id, Review review)
{
    if (id != review.Id)  
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    Review? updatedReview = this._reviewsService.UpdateReview(review);

    if (updatedReview is not null)
    {
        return review;
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

The corresponding service:

```
public Review? UpdateReview(Review updatedReview)
{
    Review? review = this._raineonContext.Reviews.Find(updatedReview.Id);

    if (review is null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Review cannot be found");
    }

    review.ReviewBody = updatedReview.ReviewBody;
    this._raineonContext.SaveChanges();

    return review;
}
```

I am expecting the updated record to save in the database and maintain the order of the records by ID in ascending order. The updated record is updated, but the order of the records by ID is altered, which I do not want.

Comment: _"then the order is saved in the database as follows:"_ - how do you check that? Also can you please post full [mre]? And lastly - if you need deterministic order - use `OrderBy` for queries.

Comment: @GuruStron My GET request for ALL Reviews returns the reviews out of order from the incrementing unique identifier. The same behavior happens in my Postgres database when I run a SELECT * FROM Reviews;

Comment: What about other points in my comment? Also have you tried to update the row via sql query directly?

Comment: Question: How do you check on that?
Answer: I ran the update/PUT request. I then proceeded to run the SELECT * on my database and my records are no longer in order by incrementing integer identifier after executing the PUT request. This unwanted behavior also happens when I run a GET request on my frontend. Yes, I could run an OrderBy, but I have never seen this unwanted behavior using other ORMs such as mongoose or sequelize. I would think the ORM shouldn't change the order of the records after update/PUT. Not sure what else I could provide for an example without posting the entire repo.

Comment: AFAIK it is the database which is responsible for the ordering in the database. You can check the query generated by EF - I highly doubt that you will find anything that changes the order of the records. Yes, full repo would be nice, cause currently there is no even a method which would return multiple entries from the repo. Again - try updating the data via SQL directly and check if the order is affected.

Comment: I confirmed that executing an UPDATE statement on the database does change the ordering of the records, though it is always assumed to be unordered according to this article I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113430/does-update-change-the-order-of-records-in-a-table-in-postgresql. Maybe I just always had a "createdAt" field the last time I used Postgres and ordered by date DESC. Thanks for your help!